# Found shared references to a collection

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a product object that contains 2 collections, accessories and consumers. Consumers relates to an accessory, the list of products that consume it. In the database I have a many to many relationship for these collections that is implemented as a linking table Product_Accessory. In mapping I have created a many to many one way for the accessories and the other way for consumers :

```
        mapping.HasManyToMany<oProduct>(x => x.Accessories)
            .Table("Product_Accessory")
            .Cascade.SaveUpdate()
            .ParentKeyColumn("ProductId")
            .ChildKeyColumn("AccessoryId")
            .AsBag();

        mapping.HasManyToMany<oProduct>(x => x.Consumers)
            .Table("Product_Accessory")
            .Cascade.SaveUpdate()
            .ParentKeyColumn("AccessoryId")
            .ChildKeyColumn("ProductId")
            .AsBag();
```

This all seems very logical but nHibernate is giving me an error of Found shared references to a collection because there are two lists of products.

Is this pattern possible using nHibernate? What is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks

Phil

Comment: Is there any reason you *need* to use the same join table for both collections? My first thought would be to use two seperate ones..

Comment: Well you could use 2 joins but the whole point of the table is to generate one record for accessories and consumers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved the issue, I had a generic function that was setting all the product collections and creating a circular reference.